# What is the best way to slurp a text file into an array/collection of std::string in C++

Tags: c++, stl

In the style of [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) I want to ask a similar question, except that I want my output to be an array/STL container containing the lines in a text file.

C#/.net has the rather useful [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) utility function, what would a good C++ (STL) version look like?

Comment: His requirements were more specific than mine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c)

Comment: Is it a dupe? I have a fixed-sized file to work from. Would @Nawaz's answer work on `cin`?

Comment: @John: Yes. My answer would work on `std::cin` also. Here is online demo : http://ideone.com/d1Ng1h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, you could do this.

- Define a struct as:

  ```
  struct line : std::string 
  {
     friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, line & ln)
     {
        return std::getline(in, ln);
     }
  };
  ```
- then do this:

  ```
  std::ifstream file("file.txt");
  std::istream_iterator<line> begin(file), end;
  std::vector<std::string> allLines(begin, end);
  ```
- Done!

With this approach, you can directly work with iterator-pair `begin` and `end`. No need to use `std::vector<std::string>`. Note that `line` can implicitly convert into `std::string`. So you can use `begin` and `end` with the Standard algorithms.

For example,

- Find the longest line:

  ```
  auto cmp = [](line const &a, line const& b) { return a.size() < b.size(); };
  std::string longestLine = *std::max_element(begin, end, cmp);
  ```
- Count the lines whose length is greater than `10`:

  ```
  auto cmp = [](line const &a) { return a.size() > 10 ; };
  size_t count = std::count_if(begin, end, cmp);
  ```
- So on. In this way, you can work directly work with `begin` and `end`. No need to use `std::vector`. Save memory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But that breaks on whitespace not newlines.

Comment: Why do you assume such a seldom situation?

Comment: @leemes: assumption removed.

Comment: Excellent fix. This now works with algorithms. I'd prefer it without the inheritance from `std::string` though.

Comment: Nice! With the `line` trick, maybe the OP could even avoid the using `vector` and use the `begin,end` range directly, depending on what he intends to do.

Comment: For beginners more complex, but more elegant than the straight-forward imperative way. I like!

Comment: Well now which one am I supposed to pick as the 'right' answer?! Think I'll have to let the votes decide it :)

Comment: Oh, can you explain this behavior? http://ideone.com/TMDpok (I'm using cin as "the file", since ideone can't process files AFAIK)

Comment: @leemes The `operator<<` is the wrong way around, Nawaz fixed it.

Comment: @leemes: it should be `operator>>`, not `<<`. I've fixed it in my answer too. See this with the fix : http://ideone.com/sfrieB

Comment: Ah, I was too slow. Fixed ideone link, maybe you want to put it in your answer: http://ideone.com/p4N8YP

Comment: Didn't see that you also fixed the ideone link ;)

Comment: This is quite neat as you save memory. Is there a way of re-winding the iterator apart from closing and re-opening the file?

Comment: @RomanKutlak: No. It is a *single-pass* input iterator, once you read data through it, it cannot go back. Read about it here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator

Comment: +1 Finally a solution for the missing "getline" stream iterator! (Though this should be a `typedef basic_line<char> line;`, right? :-) )

Answer (score 4):

The standard idiom:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
std::vector<std::string> v;

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    v.push_back(std::move(line));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ifstream ifs(name);
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifs, line))
    lines.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [my attempt](http://ideone.com/m4ReDo) at @Nawaz's idea. I've avoided inheritance from `std::string`, as I felt a little queasy about it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Line 
{
    operator const std::string&() const {return string;}
    std::string string;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Line& line)
{
    return std::getline(in, line.string);
}

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<Line> begin(std::cin), end;
    std::vector<std::string> allLines(begin, end);

    std::cout << allLines.size() << " lines read from file:" << std::endl;
    std::copy(allLines.begin(), allLines.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "|"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With this, the user wouldn't be able to write `line.size()` for example. And I don't find any reason why `line` shoudn't be derived from `std::string`. Or say why `basic_line` should not be derived from `basic_string`.  `basic_line` *is* `basic_string`. Only that they're not polymorphic.

Comment: I would only use `Line` to marshal data into `std::string`s.

Comment: I know that already from your answer. It is just that I don't find any convincing reason why `class basic_line : public std::basic_string {};` is not a good idea. I feel that nobody has done it so far, that is why many find it in the must-be-avoided category.

Comment: There are [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205050/inheriting-and-overriding-functions-of-a-stdstring) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class) about not deriving from `std::string`.

Comment: Nothing in those answers applies to this situation.

Comment: @PeterWood: Welllll.... polymorphism and inheritance are different things. It's true that there are no virtual functions in `std::basic_string`, but... so what? You only need a virtual destructor if you are handling more-derived objects through base interfaces. But no such thing is being done here. In other words, a `line` *is-not* a `string`. It's a line, and it just happens to be identical to a string.

Comment: I'm worried about object slicing. I know it's unlikely to cause a problem as `list` has no member data, but are there any dangers?